# Fancytree refresh any node (not lazy node)

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I want to refresh/reload a node in fancytree.I can reload root node using

```
$("#tree").fancytree("getRootNode").tree.reload();
```

but can't reload leaf node using this.
I also tried

```
$("#tree").fancytree("getActiveNode").tree.reload();
```

but it also reload the root node.

How to reload a leaf node(not a lazy node) in fancytree?

Comment: What so you mean by reload? Replacing that node or adding children? How do you get the new data?

Comment: I get the data by click on a node .

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

When I edit a Node

```
var node = $.ui.fancytree.getNode(e);
var parentNode = node.parent;
if (node.getLevel() != 1) {
  parentNode.load(true);
} else {
  //It's a level 1 node. So we just reload fancytree
  $.ui.fancytree.getTree().reload();
}
```

When I create a sub-node under selected node

```
var node = $.ui.fancytree.getNode(e);
node.resetLazy();
node.setExpanded(true);
```